# SQL Server2008 input to Highcharts in Asp Not Net code example

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm new to Asp.Net. I would like to chart data coming from SQL server 2008 to Highcharts. A sample code will be much appreciated. Most of the sample code which i've seen online regarding this topic doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: You are likely to get better (any) responses if you show some of your own work and what you have tried that doesn't work.  The purpose of this site is to help you solve your problem, not to solve your problem for you.